# Bash Functions: how to check if you are in an environment?

Tags: bash, function

Is it possible to check in a function if the command was executed within a specific environment or directory?
If so... How do you do it?

```
function hello(){
#Check if this environment is the hello environment
#Then do something
}
```

Comment: Alias or function? The two are quite different.

Comment: In the function Joni... thanks much

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "environment"?

Comment: virtualenv in the linux command line

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to check using normal shell constructs.

```
local env
case $(pwd) in
    /var/www/*) env=web ;;
    *) env=dunno ;;
esac
echo "You are in $env"
```